# Saving Multiple Values to Hidden Filed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using below drop-down list that allows user to select multiple values.

How can i save the selected values from drop-down list to hidden field.

**Drop Down List**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="form-control chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="Multiple Select" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Product_Name" DataValueField="Pro_ID"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**HiddenField**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSearchParam" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate, but something like this will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870516/storing-an-array-of-strings-in-a-hiddenfield-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
string selectedTexts="";
foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        selectedTexts += item.Text + " : " + item.Value + "\\n";
    }
}
hdnSearchParam.Value= selectedTexts;
```